# plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The code below throws the error `plot_confusion_matrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced', n_estimators=100))])

text_clf.fit(tokenizer.sequences_to_texts_generator(train_text_vec), y_train.argmax(axis=1)) 
predictions = text_clf.predict(tokenizer.sequences_to_texts_generator(test_text_vec))  

print('Baseline Accuracy Using Naive Bayes: ', (predictions == y_test.argmax(axis = 1)).mean()) 

print('F1 Score:', f1_score(y_test.argmax(axis = 1), predictions, average='weighted')) 

conf = plot_confusion_matrix(y_test.argmax(axis = 1), predictions, labels=encoder.classes_, title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `plot_confusion_matrix` functions does not accept a keyword argument title. You may look at the documentation of the function https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html. You should simply remove this argument.

```py
conf = plot_confusion_matrix(text_clf,
    tokenizer.sequences_to_texts_generator(test_text_vec),
    y_test.argmax(axis = 1),
    labels=encoder.classes_)
```

Comment: plot_confusion_matrix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

Comment: After removing that argument I got this TypeError

Comment: "plot_confusion_matrix() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given" After applying that statement I got these error

Comment: You are correct, the predictions should not be given, I updated the answer. All of this are described on the docs. I am not able to execute your code since parts are missing, so if there is any other error you may check the function documentation for details